# Malloc attempts to address 0x0?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm working with dynamic memory in C. I'm writing a small function which should

1. take a string (a char*) as a parameter;
2. allocate memory with malloc for that string, copy it into the memory; and
3. return the newly allocated string.

My program gives a segmentation fault.

```
char *new_line(char *line) {
        char *temp_line;
        int line_len = strlen(line)+1;
        temp_line = malloc(line_len * sizeof(char));
        printf(temp_line);
        strncpy(temp_line,line,line_len);
        return temp_line;
}
```

According to GDB, my program fails on this function, because apparently it is trying to do something (?) to the address 0x0.
This is what GDB says:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7b7c3c1 in __strlen_sse2_pminub () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000000004008fc in new_line (line=0x0) at myfile.c:35
```

Can anyone offer some insight on why malloc seems to be returning or messing with 0x0, based on my function? I can't see it.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Huh? The stack trace shows me that ***strlen*** not malloc is addressing 0x0.

Comment: The error message says `(line=0x0)` which means you passed a `NULL` pointer to the function.

Comment: Are you passing a NULL pointer (0x0) or a valid string into `new_line()`?

Comment: You could use strdup which does exactly this (though isn't very portable).

Answer (score 2):

```
#0  0x00007ffff7b7c3c1 in __strlen_sse2_pminub () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

It's `strlen` that's crashing, not `malloc`.

```
#1  0x00000000004008fc in new_line (line=0x0) at myfile.c:35
```

Notice it says `line=0x0`. That means `line` is NULL. The code that calls `new_line` is passing a null pointer.

```
int line_len = strlen(line)+1;
```

Which in turn causes `strlen` to be given a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` uses `strlen` internally.

You're calling `printf` on a buffer from `malloc` that has [possibly] random characters in it [it does *not* initialize the bytes]. So, `strlen` may just "keep going".

Move the `printf` after the `strncpy`

Answer (score 1):

There are following issues.

1. The major issue is that you are printing new string before copying data to it. The allocated memory will have some random data.
2. It is better to check whether memory allocation is successful. Also check the input pointer.
3. `strncpy()` will not put `'\0'` at the end. You need to put it explicitly. Since, in this case you have allocated memory by checking size of input string, you can call `strcpy()`.

   > ```
   > char *new_line(char *line) {
   >         char *temp_line = 0;
   >
   >         if(0 == line)
   >         {
   >             printf("Input is null\n");
   >             return 0
   >         }
   >
   >         int line_len = strlen(line)+1;
   >         temp_line = malloc(line_len * sizeof(char));
   >         if(0 == temp_line)
   >         {
   >             printf("Failed to allocate memory for new string\n");
   >             return 0;
   >         }
   >
   >         strncpy(temp_line,line,line_len);
   >         temp_line[line_len-1] = '\0';
   >         /* You can replace above two lines with strcpy(). */
   >
   >         printf("Inp string[%s] new string[%s]\n", line, temp_line);
   >
   >         return temp_line;
   > }
   > ```